# Webapp2 List (and/or kill) All Sessions for User (Appengine Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, python-2.7, webapp2

I'm working on an appengine app using webapp2. I based my authentication off of the ideas put forward in [this article](http://blog.abahgat.com/2013/01/07/user-authentication-with-webapp2-on-google-app-engine/).

I added the ability to delete an account (it's a requirement of the app), and I've run into an issue with sessions. If the user is logged in from more than one location, there will be two auth tokens for that user. When the account is deleted from one of those logins, the session for that login is destroyed. However, the other login will have an auth token in the datastore.

I altered the `user_required`/`check_login` decorator/function so that it first looks for a user in the session. If it doesn't find one, I let the client know that they need to login in. If it does find one, I then get the user from the datastore. If it is None, then I assume that there were multiple logins, and a different one deleted the account (which also deletes the User). Therefore, I kill the session, and tell the client that the User no longer exists. Otherwise, I check if the user is verified, and if it isn't I tell the client that the User has to be verified before it could do anything.

I'd rather be able to kill all the sessions for a user if the account is deleted. Is there any way to do this? I would also want this functionality so that I can have a feature where a logged in user can see all of the sessions for that user, and kill/revoke them at will (sort of like what Facebook and Google, and I'm sure plenty of other services) offer.

**EDIT:** Even though I'd probably end up getting the user from the datastore at some point anyways, and when I call `self.user` it is a `webapp2.cached_property`, I still would rather not **have** to get the user at the beginning of every request decorated with `user_required` if I can maybe get away with only pulling the info from the session.

Comment: If you are checking the session of the user on every request against the datastore then I think you are already doing all you can. Unless you are actually asking whether or not it is possible to delete cookies on your users' computers in which case, well, that is not possible.

Comment: @dlebech When I say get rid of the session I mean take it out of the datastore, so that the next time the user tried to get on with that login, the user_required method will say there is no user for this session. This would be the case whether it was because the user deleted the account, or because the user revoked that session (if I would be able to list all the current sessions for that user and allow the user to "revoke/delete" a session (meaning getting rid of it in the data store))

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In that case, I think [the answer from dragonx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447663/2021517) is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the datastore backend for sessions.

The best way is probably to modify the session framework so that the session entity stores your user id.  That way you can query for session entities by user id, then delete them and flush them out of memcache.

Alternatively you can store your sessions in your User entity, and when you delete the User, go through that list and get rid of all the sessions.  Might be a bit of a pain to clean out expiring sessions from the User entity though.

Comment: How would I modify the session framework? Would it be something like subclassing `DatastoreSessionFactory`? You also mentioned cleaning out expiring sessions. Should I have a cron job that runs every x and deletes tokens that have expired, or does the framework handle that?